# How to create an Image manupulation interface in iPhone with overlay for crop area

Tags: ios4, uiscrollview, touch

I have an iPhone application in which the a photo chosen by the user displays in a editing view. The photo is visible under a semi transparent overlay and there is a oval hole in the overlay according to which the underlying image gets cropped, when user taps finish after panning, rotating and zooming the image.

My question is:

1. Is there any available library which enables to do the whole functionality? I ask this because I have seen this kind of image editing interface in many apps.
2. Is there any way to propagate the touch on the overlay to the underlying scrollview, so that when the user makes gestures for scroll/rotate/zoom on the overlay, the scrollview with image underneath the overlay responds to that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"Touch began");
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView: imageScrollView];
    [imageScrollView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

and this link helped for all the rotation/panning/zoom and everything:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-winter

See **"14_MultiTouchDemo.zip"** under **"Title: Lecture #14 - MultiTouch"**

Direct Download link of Sample Files:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/14_MultiTouchDemo.zip